# iOS ASI Chunked uploading?

Tags: ios, file-upload, asihttprequest

I've read the documentation on ASI, and don't really know if it can handle chunked uploading, and if it does, how to do it.

I have an iOS App that uploads video to our servers using ASI.  I'm getting incomplete files due to connection issues (losing and regaining connection), and I'd like to eliminate this issue by chunked uploading.  Any ideas on how to do that with ASI?  Any other iOS libraries that handle this?

Comment: I am also about to develop an App to upload more or less 350Mb video file from IOS device to S3 server.
Did you find the solution of your issue ?

Comment: I just built it myself.  Used an initial POST to tell our servers a file is being sent.  POSTs for each chunk of file send.  And a POST when it was completed